# TMUX typing goes to every split window

Tags: tmux

Whenever I type into a split window in tmux, my typing goes into every window.

Is there a way to toggle this?

Tried googling but no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1):

```
set-window-option [-agqu] [-t target-window] option value (alias: setw)
        synchronize-panes [on | off]
                  Duplicate input to any pane to all other panes in the same window (only for panes that are not in any special mode).
```